# Topological Equivalence Practice Problems?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

I have just learned how to prove topological equivalence of two subspaces by finding (of proving the existence of) a continuous function and its inverse from one to the other. However, all of the problems that I come up with for myself are too difficult.

Can anybody recommend some easy to moderately challenging practice problems regarding topological equivalence? So far, I have proven the topological equivalence of:

- all closed intervals $[a,b]$ on the real line
- all open intervals $(a,b)$ and the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$ on the real line
- the open-bordered unit square and the entire Cartesian Coordinate Plane in Euclidean $2$-space

I would also appreciate any tips about proving topological equivalence.

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a fun exercise: determine which of the letters of the alphabet are homeomorphic to each other and which aren't (uppercase and lowercase). Once you learn a little algebraic topology, you can repeat the same exercise with homotopy equivalence instead of homeomorphism (I think this is an exercise in Hatcher, maybe).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Haha! That sounds fun... it also sounds like it would be challenging to represent the letters of the alphabet mathematically. It seems like it would be easy to *determine*, but hard to *prove*.

Comment: Eh, just draw some lines. The answer might depend on the font you're using but that's okay, just means more letters to figure out.

Comment: Btw in your bio you mean compact. You can find continuous functions that take a closed subset of a metric space to a non closed one (and example is already in the body of your question.) But the continuous image of a compact subset is always compact (exercise).

Comment: @AreaMan Whoops, thanks - I was confusing that with the fact that the  *inverse* of a continuous function $f:X\to Y$ preserves closeness of closed sets $A\in Y$.

Comment: The three spaces $\mathbb  Q\cap (0,1),\;$ $ \mathbb Q\cap [0,1),\; $ $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ are homeomorphic to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to prove that the closed interval and the circle are not homeomorphic. (The analogous problem for higher dimensions requires some algebraic topology.)

With the same idea, prove that the line is not homeomorphic to the plane.

You can try to prove that any injective continuous map from the closed (and bounded) interval into the plane is a homeomorphism onto it's image (with the subspace topology). Give a counter example if you work with the open interval instead.

You can classify the homeomorphism types of 1 dimensional manifolds without boundary. (This one might be tedious to do in detail. The others are essentially one liners, though they require clever ideas.)

You can pick a small integer n (say, 2 or 3 or 4) and see what you can say about the different topologies on a set with n elements. How many homeomorphism types are there?

Comment: Thanks for the interesting problems! I will try them!